# How to trace wait() and fork() commands

Tags: c, fork

I am having some difficulty understanding how and when child processes return to the parent. Look at this example which I put together using various sites:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
   int i;
   int pid;
   int wpid;
   int status;

   time1.tv_sec = 5L;
   time1.tv_nsec = 0L;

   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
      pid = fork();

      if ( pid < 0 ) {
         printf ( "Error" );
         exit ( 1 );
      }
      else if ( pid  == 0 ) {
         break;
      }
   }

   while ( ( wpid = wait ( &status ) ) > 0 )
   {
      printf ( "Exit status of %d was %d (%s)\n", ( int ) wpid, status, ( status == 0 ) ? "accept" : "reject" );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is what exactly does the child return, and when/where? After the `fork` command, the child enter the second loop, but it will never exit that loop to go further down and reach the return command. Am I supposed to put a conditional so only the parent carries out that loop? Does the child ignore the `wait()` command?

I find this is one question where veteran programmers don't dumb it down enough for people like me. I could not find a single answer which addressed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `wait` receives the exit code of the process, which is an `int`. The value can be set, for example, by `exit(1)`

Your code reads as follows

```
time1.tv_nsec = 0L; // only "parent" thread here.

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
  pid = fork();  // create a child.

  if ( pid < 0 ) {   //
     printf ( "Error" );
     exit ( 1 );
  }
  else if ( pid  == 0 ) { // only the child will enter this if, so it will exit the loop.
     break;
  }
}

 while ( ( wpid = wait ( &status ) ) > 0 )  // children and parent run this condition, but the
                                            // children don't have children so they will just
                                            // exit the wait function with -1, so they don't run
                                            // loop
 {
    printf ( "Exit status of %d was %d (%s)\n", ( int ) wpid, status, ( status == 0 ) ? "accept" : "reject" );  // only the parent executes this
 }

 return 0;   // return from main, this value is the one that will be received by the wait (in case
             // of children processes. There is also the option of using exit(0); exit ends program
             // execution everywhere it is used.
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `fork`, the child process *and* the parent process start at the same place: right after the call to `fork`. The only difference is, `fork` returns 0 for the child process and the PID of the child process (> 0) to the parent process. That's why you need a conditional right after the call to `fork`.

So in your child process, it will check for the return value 0 and break, where it goes into the `while` loop. The parent process will stay in the `for` loop, where it will keep forking child processes until the it's finished. Then it will go into the `while` loop.

In your child process, the `wait()` function is probably returning `ECHILD` (see [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)) because there are no children, so you should make sure the child threads aren't calling it or make sure they handle errors gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's take a look at how `fork()` works.

When `fork` is invoked a new process is created by cloning the process which invokes it. This process (from now on the **child**) is an **exact** copy of the first one (the **parent** process). This means that both processes will continue executing at the command following the `fork()`.

Now, how do you distinguish which one is the parent and which one is the child? Based on the return status of `fork()`.

> Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process
>   and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent
>   process.

So, if we suppose that everything went OK and no error happened, the `break;` statement of your code gets executed at the child process, and the parent continues to spawn children until the loop finishes.

Now, after `break;` each child finds itself `wait`ing. From the manpage of `wait()`:

> wait, waitpid - wait for a child process to stop or terminate

But wait a second! Each of the child processes does not have a child to wait for! So `wait()` fails with `ECHILD` and the children terminate.

Also, after executing all loop iterations, the parent process will find itself `wait`ing. The parent process has several children, and gets the exit status of them, one in a time when they terminate. Children do not terminate in any particular order, it's up to the operating system and you cannot assume one is going to terminate before another.

I hope that the above clarify things and to be now able to fix your code to make it work.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to provide the conditional logic which will guide the child process in its work.  Since the fork will set the parent's stack variable and not the stack value of the child, you can do the following:

```
 pid_t pid1 = 0;

 printf("*** Parent is about to fork process 1 ***\n");
 if ((pid1 = fork()) < 0) {
      printf("Failed to fork process 1\n");
      exit(1);
 }
 else if (pid1 == 0)
 {
      // Work of the child process
 }
 else 
 {
      // Work of the parent process
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, my question pertained to a condition around the `wait()` and not the `fork()` (which I am aware will need some conditionals after to prevent infinite children.